# How to use comparison operator correctly in this case? (string array[0][0] == "string")

Tags: c++, arrays, string, comparison-operators

I need to compare a character in a string that is in an array with another string. This is a functioning but simple version of my problem:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    
    string a_ray[1] = {"asd"};
    if (a_ray[0][0] == "a") {
        bool a;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Error message: `ISO C++ forbids comparison between pointer and integer [-fpermissive]|`

What causes this? And how can I do what I want to do in the correct way?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Are you trying to compare characters or strings? Your question title and body differ. In your example code, `a_ray[0][0]` is a `char` and `"a"` is a `const char[2]`. If you're trying to compare a single character, Tanveer's answer is correct.

Comment: `"a"` and `'a'` are two different things.

Comment: oooooooooohhhhh gotcha!!!!!

Answer (score 2):

Since you are comparing against a character, your code should be

```
if (a_ray[0][0] == 'a')
```

You are trying to compare a character with a character array, hence the error message.